# I can´t get access to the values of an javascript object retrieved from firebase

Tags: firebase

Hi I´ve tried many ways to get it but I am lost.

This is my function:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<my-url>.firebaseio.com/");
    var ref2 = ref.orderByChild("matricula").equalTo(matricula);
    var ref3 = ref2.on("value", function(snapshot){

        console.log(snapshot.numChildren());
        console.log(snapshot.val());
        }
```

And the objet retrieved is:

```
Object {-KACGpGoGlVbgbHM4ibI: Object}
-KACGpGoGlVbgbHM4ibI: Object
carrera: "LAMX54"
comentarios: " "
curp: "rffgr4445454445"
matricula: "006843"
nombre: "JOSE GERARDO LOPEZ VILLARREAL"
postulado: "no"
tetra: "7"
__proto__: Object
__proto__: Object
```

Ok, when I try to get snapshot.val().carrera for example the response is "undefined", even when I tried get snapshot.key() the response is "null" , how can I get the values inside the Object?, thanks in advance!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you execute a query, you can have potentially many child nodes matching the condition. So your `value` event will be triggered with a collection of child nodes. Even when there's only a single child, it will still be in a collection.

To handle this, you need to loop over the children:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://<my-url>.firebaseio.com/");
var ref2 = ref.orderByChild("matricula").equalTo(matricula);
var ref3 = ref2.on("value", function(parent){
    console.log(parent.numChildren());
    console.log(parent.val());
    parent.forEach(function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.val().carrera);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am learning about angular and firebase actually I have a new post, I think more complicated that this one :( , It would be great if you could check it out! Here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35562167/animations-does-not-working-with-angular